# How to remove the outline of joint text in after effect?

Tags: text, adobe-after-effects

[image]

I have inserted glow effect to this text. I want to combine overlapping characters so that they have only one outline. How it can be done?

Comment: I don't know if After Effects has boolean operations you can apply to vectors, if not then just use Illustrator to create them. With Illustrator you can select multiple letters and do Unite in the Pathfinder. Then import into AE.  This question might be better suited to the [Video Production Stack Exhange](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If you using text generator inside AE (text tool) you can add a tracking animator.[image]